# Using a C# multiselect checkedlistbox to add to an SQL server as each selected option in the checkedlistbox being entered as a comma separated string

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, visual-studio

I don't know if the title really explains what I want to do very well, so i'll try to explain it here.

I have a checkedlistbox that will allow the user to multiselect options in it. I want those options then to save to the SQL server as a string of all the options selected separated by commas.

like if I have a checkedlistbox with the options 'a', 'b' and 'c' and a user selects 'a' and 'c' is there anyway to get the SQL to recognize that as "a, c"?

Comment: Of course there's a way. But - you will have to edit your question and add your code, otherwise, we can't help you at all.

Comment: I believe it's not considered good practice to store multiple pieces of data in a single column; maybe your answer is just changing the design a bit.

Comment: Yeah I ended up just redesigning how some of the information is conveyed

Answer (score 0):

You can use String.Join([array],[character]) this function will return and string joined by the character specified

```
    var arOptions = {"1","2","3"};
    var strLine = String.Join(arOptions,'|');
```

Answer (score 0):

Get all checked items and then join them into string:

```
string selectedItems = 
       string.Join(", ", myCheckedlistbox .CheckedItems.Cast<string>().ToArray());
```